# PIP install packages but some not found

Tags: python, pip, installation, pywinauto

Some pip installs don't work on a computer, since recently I changed to Python 3.

for example, pywinauto

I used CMD:

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip install pywinauto
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip freeze
```

It shows:

```
pywinauto==0.6.8
```

But when I:

```
import pywinauto
```

It gives:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywinauto'
```

I moved the 2 folders "pywinauto" and "pywinauto-0.6.8.dist-info" from:

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\
```

To:

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
```

And:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\Scripts\\')
```

It still doesn't work. (it works for some other cases)

Windows 64 settings seem ok with: Environment Variables > User variables

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages
```

Environment Variables > System variables

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages
```

p.s. I have Anaconda installed in the machine, and no Python 2. Not sure whether it causes the problem.

Comment: sorry i saw first line of your code that tried in CMD

Comment: `python3 -m pip install <package>` or `python_path -m pip install <package>` can you try this and show your result?

Comment: @Tserenjamts, I used "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>python3 -m pip install pywinauto". Strangely it doesn't give anything. Only a enter to new line.

Comment: How strange is it this need to be discussed or there are other things we can't notice which is already found by others. Need to search more. I am searching too hha.

Comment: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ Did you do manual installation step in pywinauto site?

Comment: @Tserenjamts, pip install can do. I figured out a way. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your **conda** terminal, activate the **virtual environment**.
2. pip install <*your package name*>.
3. Now go to your editor where you're running this code. (like pycharm or Sublime)
4. select your python interpreter as venv (Anaconda). Usually this option is available in project setting.
   Run your code, it should work now.

Comment: thank you for the help. However I cannot find the "pywinauto" in my Anaconda terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the problem relates to Anaconda.

Problem solved by run CMD:

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts>pip instsall pywinauto
```

Then manually moved the 2 folders "pywinauto" and "pywinauto-0.6.8.dist-info" from:

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\
```

To:

```
C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3
```

The package functions normally.

Comment: Absolutely, it is related to anaconda not environment variables.

Comment: Another way you can use full path to `pip.exe` to ensure it's used from correct Python / Anaconda distro. "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: @Vasily Ryabov, thanks for the comment. I experimented it - when pointed the explicit (anaconda3 this case) folder, pip took longer time and installed more sub-folders to it. When "import pywinauto", it gives "ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application." So finally I came back to the regular pip install way, and manually moved the 2 sub-folders to "anaconda3". It works. :)

Comment: @MarkK thanks for the info. We may need to check it.